# Neo4j 4.0.0 throwing NullPointerException

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

I am a new bee in spring boot and ne04j .I am working on project which contains 2 modules web and core .Web (package as a war) module contains spring controllers and Core (package as a jar) modules contains neo4j repository and domain .Web module include Core module as a jar .When I run project using java -jar web/target/my-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war its throwing NullPointerException .

Spring Boot version : 1.3.0.RELEASE
Neo4j  : 4.0.0.RELEASE

below are the logs

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) [jetty-security-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544) [jetty-io-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar!/:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.MetaData.entityType(MetaData.java:231) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
>       at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.entityType(Neo4jSession.java:451) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
>       at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:55) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
>       at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:99) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
>       at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.loadAll(Neo4jSession.java:119) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar!/:na]
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepositoryImpl.findAll(GraphRepositoryImpl.java:123) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
>       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepositoryImpl.findAll(GraphRepositoryImpl.java:118) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:475) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:432) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at com.ng.adm.neo.serviceImpl.TaskServiceImpl.tasks(TaskServiceImpl.java:22) ~[adm-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.tasks(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at com.ng.adm.web.controllers.TaskApiController.tasks(TaskApiController.java:34) ~[classes!/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]

Below is my controller from web module (inside war)

```
enter code here

@Controller("")
public class TaskApiController {

    @Autowired
    TaskService taskService;

    @Autowired
    TaskRepository repository; 

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "api/tasks", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<Task> tasks(@RequestParam(value = "limit",required = false) Integer limit) {
        return taskService.tasks(limit == null ? 100 : limit);
    }

}
```

Below is the Neo4j domain from Core module (inside jar)

```
enter code here

Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "neo4j")
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("com.ng.adm.neo")
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration{

    private String protocol;
    private String host;
    private String port;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String url;
    private String domainPackage;

    @Bean
    public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
        return new RemoteServer(this.protocol+this.host+":"+this.port,this.userName,this.password);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory(this.domainPackage);
    }



    public String getProtocol() {
        return protocol;
    }

    public void setProtocol(String protocol) {
        this.protocol = protocol;
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public String getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(String port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getDomainPackage() {
        return domainPackage;
    }

    public void setDomainPackage(String domainPackage) {
        this.domainPackage = domainPackage;
    }   
}
```

Below is the Neo4j Configuration from Core module (inside jar)

```
enter code here

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=JSOGGenerator.class)
@NodeEntity
public class Task {

    @GraphId Long id;
    String taskName;
    String taskDescription;
    String taskPriority;
    String taskStatus;
    int taskArchived = 0;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getTaskArchived() {
        return taskArchived;
    }

    public String getTaskName() {
        return taskName;
    }

    public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
        this.taskName = taskName;
    }

    public String getTaskDescription() {
        return taskDescription;
    }

    public void setTaskDescription(String taskDescription) {
        this.taskDescription = taskDescription;
    }

    public String getTaskPriority() {
        return taskPriority;
    }

    public void setTaskPriority(String taskPriority) {
        this.taskPriority = taskPriority;
    }

    public String getTaskStatus() {
        return taskStatus;
    }

    public void setTaskStatus(String taskStatus) {
        this.taskStatus = taskStatus;
    }

    public int isTaskArchived() {
        return taskArchived;
    }

    public void setTaskArchived(int taskArchived) {
        this.taskArchived = taskArchived;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Task [id=" + id + ", taskName=" + taskName
                + ", taskDescription=" + taskDescription + ", taskPriority="
                + taskPriority + ",taskStatus=" + taskStatus + "]";
    }

}
enter code here

Below is my repository from Core module (inside Jar)

    enter code here

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "tasks", path = "tasks")
public interface TaskRepository extends GraphRepository<Task> {

    List<Task> findByTaskArchived(@Param("archivedfalse") int taskArchivedFalse);
    List<Task> findByTaskStatus(@Param("status") String taskStatus);

    /*Student findByFirstName(@Param("firstName") String fname);

    @Query("MATCH (n:Student) RETURN n LIMIT {limit}")
    List<Map<String,Object>> students(@Param("limit") int limit);*/
}
```

Below is my service class from from Core module (inside jar)

```
enter code here


@Service
@Transactional
public class TaskServiceImpl implements TaskService{

    @Autowired TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Task> tasks(int limit) {
        Iterable<Task> result = taskRepository.findAll();
        return (List<Task>) AppUtils.makeCollection(result);
    }

}
```

its working when I am running project from mvn spring-boot:run command but getting exception from command java -jar web/target/my-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war .

Please help me in finding the issue .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Was this ever resolved?  I'm running into the same issue, and updating to 1.1.4 did not solve.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error, and it was due to my domain package being incorrect in the SessionFactory bean.

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return new SessionFactory("com.make.sure.this.is.right");
}
```

Note, you can pass in multiple package parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Think this issue was fixed- please upgrade the neo4j-ogm dependency version to 1.1.4